# How can I pass an Azure Active Directory's App roles to an App through a JWT token?

Tags: azure-active-directory, roles, user-roles, azure-app-registration

We have an application with is registered in Azure Active Directory as "Foo".  One of its App Roles is "Foo.Admin", which is required to administer the application.  It allows Users as a member type.

We have a user John Doe (john.doe@example.com) who is an Azure Active Directory User who has been assigned the App Role "Foo.Admin".  He uses the Registered App "Bar", whose client id and client secret we use when we request a JWT token from Azure Active Directory like:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/ebb73ad2-08da-11ed-861d-0242ac120002/oauth2/v2.0/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Cookie: fpc=f89f219c08da11ed861d0242ac120002; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
--data-urlencode 'username=john.doe@example.com' \
--data-urlencode 'password=1e173716-08db-11ed-861d-0242ac120002' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=api://foo/.default' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=126ed4b4-08db-11ed-861d-0242ac120002' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=197710d2-08db-11ed-861d-0242ac120002'
```

(not real password and secret, duh!)

Unfortunately (though I know not to be surprised), the App Role is not included in the resulting JWT Token.

I read somewhere I might be able to fix this by putting *something* in some manifest.

But I'm clear neither what to put in the manifest, nor whether this belongs in the manifest for "Foo" (the application with the App Role) or for "Bar" (the application John Doe is using).

Any ideas how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

By default these app roles are included in the token as the claim named `roles`

What you've read about the manifest is likely for creating the app roles - the **App roles** blade you see in the Portal UI is recently new, you previously had to directly edit the manifest. If you open the manifest, you'll see the JSON representation of your app roles under the `appRoles` key.

If I'm understanding you correctly, the app roles should be created under **Bar**, the application John is signing into.

I think this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps#usage-scenario-of-app-roles) should be helpful for you.

> If you're implementing app role business logic that signs in the users in your application scenario, first define the app roles in App registrations. Then, an admin assigns them to users and groups in the Enterprise applications pane. These assigned app roles are included with any token that's issued for your application, either access tokens when your app is the API being called by an app or ID tokens when your app is signing in a user.
>
> If you're implementing app role business logic in an app-calling-API scenario, you have two app registrations. One app registration is for the app, and a second app registration is for the API. In this case, define the app roles and assign them to the user or group in the app registration of the API. When the user authenticates with the app and requests an access token to call the API, a roles claim is included in the access token. Your next step is to add code to your web API to check for those roles when the API is called.

Comment: I'm afraid there may be some misunderstanding.  In this case I don't want to assign the app role to the application but the user, which I've enabled and can do.  However by default this is not included when I request the JWT from AzureAD.  If the role were assigned to the application, yes it would be there, but that is not what I presently want.

Comment: No I understand that, and my answer above doesn't change. However, does the received token contain **any** information about John? Because I can see you're using the `client_credentials` grant type, which is used for **applications** to sign-in, not users, and I see you're adding username and password.

Comment: No, I don't see anything about John.  If I should change the grant type or anything else to get this to work, please let me know.  The only things I care about is that the permission is granted to directly to the User and is present in the JWT.

Comment: Ok this explains why I was having trouble understanding your scenario, you might have some fundamental issues here. I'm not sure where to start - from your information I don't actually see the relation between Foo and Bar, you would just setup Foo to sign users in using OpenID Connect, and then create the app roles under Foo.

Comment: can you please elaborate on "just setup Foo to sign users in using OpenID Connect,", as I have no idea what this means.  The role already exists and has already been assigned to the User.  I don't really care about Bar.  I only care that the App Role appears in the JWT.  I needed (or think I needed) an app for a client id and client secret to submit the request for a JWT to AzureAd.

Comment: OIDC is an SSO protocol that's built upon the OAuth standards, you need this configured to allow your application to sign users in. From the Azure AD side this is fairly simple to configure - go to your App Registration, go to the Authentication blade, add your platform (web server, web SPA, native?) including your callback URL and select the checkbox for ID tokens. You'll need to configure the application side as well. I suggest reviewing the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc)

Comment: Do I want to go to the Authentication blade for Foo or for Bar?  Do I need to create somewhere that Azure needs to callback to?  I looked at the MS documentation and I don't even see anything about Roles on the page.